# How do I generate an SSHFP record for a Mikrotik router?

Tags: ssh, mikrotik, dane

I want to generate an SSHFP record for my Mikrotik CCR2004 running RouterOS 6.47.4, without getting the key over the network.  How can I do this from the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regenerate the host key if needed (e.g. if changing the modulus length):

```
ip ssh regenerate-host-key
```

The CLI will hang for a moment.  When it's back:

```
ip ssh export-host-key
file print
```

You'll get something like:

```
[admin@MikroTik] > file print
 # NAME                   TYPE                        SIZE CREATION-TIME
 0 hostKey_rsa            file                        3272 jan/03/1970 18:35:53
 1 hostKey_rsa.pub        ssh key                      796 jan/03/1970 18:35:53
 2 hostKey_dsa            file                         668 jan/03/1970 18:35:53
 3 hostKey_dsa.pub        ssh key                      604 jan/03/1970 18:35:53
```

Print the one you want:

```
file print detail where name=hostKey_rsa.pub
```

Remove the extra spaces from the beginning of the printed key, and put it in a file e.g. router_pubkey.pem.  Then on your box:

```
openssl rsa -in router_pubkey.pem -pubin -RSAPublicKey_out |
  ssh-keygen -f /dev/stdin -i -m PEM |
  ssh-keygen -f /dev/stdin -r hostname
```

The openssl command converts the key to PKCS#1 format (just an integer sequence, instead of an ASN.1 rsaEncryption object).  The ssh-keygen invocations respectively import the key into OpenSSH format, and then generate the fingerprints and print SSHFP records.